# Modules in puppet environment not in module path

Tags: puppet

According to the Puppet documentation the modules in the active environment is supposed to be on the module path. However when I run the following command:

```
puppet agent --configprint modulepath
```

I only see "/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules" and not the modules in the environment as well.

Is there some configuration option that needs to be set to have the active environment's modules in the module path?

Comment: I fixed the problem by setting 'environmentpath' in the [main] section of the puppet.conf file. I had the setting under the [master] section previously.

Comment: you should create an answer to reflect your solution and accept it as the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by setting 'environmentpath' in the [main] section of the puppet.conf file. I had the setting under the [master] section previously.